# How are @TransitionFrom and @TransitionTo supposed to be used

Tags: java, jfr

The Java Flight Recorder API contains two annotations [TransitionFrom](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.jfr/jdk/jfr/TransitionFrom.html) and [TransitionTo](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.jfr/jdk/jfr/TransitionTo.html) but the documentation is very light on how they should be used.

How are they supposed to be used? I assume they go on fields of events. Should they be boolean or thread fields? When should the fields be set to which values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of @TransitionTo and @TransitionFrom is to hint to a graphical user interface like JDK Mission Control that there is a transition from thread A to thread B.

The GUI can then visualize it as transition arrows:

[image: Transition Graph]

If you commit the event in thread A, you would create a thread field and annotate it with @TransitionTo and assign thread B to it.

```
@Name("com.organization.product.Notification")
@Label("Notification")
public class Notification extends jdk.jfr.Event {
   @TransitionTo
   @Label ("Receiver");
   Thread receiver;
}
```

If it is more convenient to commit the event in thread B, you would create a field annotated with @TransitionFrom and assign it with thread A instead.

```
@Name("com.organization.product.Notification")
@Label("Notification")
public class Notification extends jdk.jfr.Event {
   @TransitionFrom
   @Label ("Notifier");
   Thread notifier;
}
```